# How to click a button by name or text with puppeteer?

Tags: node.js, puppeteer

I am new to puppeteer and stuck in trying to click a certain button on yahoo. I face the following situation:

[image]

[image]

I tried to select click on the button as follows:

```
const [button] = await page.$x("//button[contains(., 'OK')]");
if (button) {
   await button.click();
}
```

Unfortunately without success.
How would I click on the OK button in general? And what would be a solution to check whether the button exists or not. Thank you very much for your help.

Comment: Your xpath looks OK. Possibly you're being blocked as a bot, the element is in an iframe, or the selector appears after the page load. Try `waitForXPath`.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

From your browser, open the page where the button sits. 
Right click on the page and select "Inspect".

Then, from the DOM code, right click on the button, and select "Copy > Copy JS path".

That selector can be easily used in puppeteer.

Comment: this is not working for me as js path takes the ID of the tag, which is changed each time a page is reloaded

Comment: If the ID is changing, you may need to use a different way to identify the element on the page. Maybe the `:nth-child()` selector? I don't know what's your case, so I can't really suggest a more specific approach. Try to ask a question for your own case and see if anybody has a better solution  :)

Comment: This only works if you know the JS path, i.e. if you run into a cookies page you do not necessarily know the path.

Comment: if your button has an id and a name, but you want to use the name, this approach do not work.

Comment: Be careful with this approach. Playwright (similar to Puppeteer) [cautions against it](https://playwright.dev/docs/locators#locate-by-css-or-xpath), [as do I](https://serpapi.com/blog/puppeteer-antipatterns/#misusing-developer-tools-generated-selectors). "XPath and CSS selectors can be tied to the DOM structure or implementation. These selectors can break when the DOM structure changes. Long CSS or XPath chains below are an example of a bad practice that leads to unstable tests: [long browser-generated selector]"

Answer (score 21):

You can use the name attribute as a selector for name:

```
await page.waitForSelector('button[name="agree"]');
await page.click('button[name="agree"]');
```